# Why isn't the context of 'this' in Javascript not changing in this example?

Tags: javascript, this

I am experimenting with the context of  'this' in Javascript and I have a situation that I don't understand.

Based on the way javascript works found from [here](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/), I understand that when a function is called on an object, the object is implicitly passed in as the firest parameter (or explicitly when using the `call` method.

But there are 2 cases that I tried to test that didn't do what I expected. Please look at the 2 lines after *//Why doesn't ths work? Why are the follwoing 2 values undefined?*

Here is the code in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehT4b/7/) (also pasted below)

```
function Beta(c, myValParam) {
  var callback = c;
  this.myVal = myValParam;
  this.RunCallback = function () {
   callback();
  }

  this.ShowVal = function () {
    alert("FROM Beta: " + this.myVal);
  }
}

function Alpha() {
  this.myVal = "Alpha's Property";
  this.ShowVal = function () {
    alert("FROM Alpha: " + this.myVal);
  }
}
a = new Alpha();
a.ShowVal();

b = new Beta(a.ShowVal, "Beta's property passed in");
b.ShowVal();

//Why doesn't ths work? Why are the follwoing 2 values undefined?
b.RunCallback.call(b); //Shouldn't this display the value in b?
b.RunCallback();

b2 = new Beta(function() { return a.ShowVal.call(a); }, "Z");
b2.RunCallback();
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to the answers from Quentin, dystroy and dough, I've [updated the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehT4b/10/) to show the values produced when the context reverts to the window object

And here is the [code with the call to](http://jsfiddle.net/ehT4b/11/) `callback.call(this)` which fixes the problem I was having

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't this display the value in b?

You are calling (in the context of `b`) a function which does nothing with `this`. That function calls `callback` (which is a copy of `a.showVal`) in the context of `window` (the default object).

Comment: So, passing in a function as a paramter for a callback does NOT also pass in the context? i.e. this line: 
`b = new Beta(a.ShowVal, "Beta's property passed in");` does not pass in the context of a. It's just a copy of `ShowVal`

Comment: No. The context is determined by how a function is called (i.e. with `new`, with `call`/`apply` or on an object (`object.function()`) with `window` being the default object. (And then there is `bind` which I haven't looked at closely yet).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I've updated my question with a working example

Answer (score 1):

You forgot one step in the definition of `RunCallback` :

Replace

```
callback();
```

with

```
callback.call(this);
```

Comment: Shazzam!, that works, but I still need help understanding that, why does it show undefined at all? Without your modification, what is the context it is running in?

Comment: this is never undefined. It's window (the global context) if no context is passed.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that when you invoke `callback` you're not passing a context so you're losing `this`.  Try updating RunCallback like this:

```
  this.RunCallback = function () {
   callback.call(this);
  }
```